# Can not find image on Wordpress Nav

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am currently developing a site for a client based on a previous theme they have. I am trying to add in the styling they wanted but I am not able to find, what I believe are images, on the side of the navbar. I have searched through the entire theme folder and are not seeing them.

The dev link is, http://gator4034.hostgator.com/~lmn927/

If anyone can tell me or point me in the right direction as to where they are that would be great!

Comment: What are we supposed to do with the dev link?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Do you mean the white triangles on the navigation bar?

Comment: @vinsanity38 Yes that is exactly what I am referring too. Is that an image created using js? I am digging through the code but not seeing anything.

Comment: @aDroidman.  This is not an image, they are using CSS3 to create the triangles and positioning them on the navigation bar

Comment: @aDroidman just do a google search of "CSS3 shapes" and you'll find a lot of documentation on how to create such images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images (white triangles) you are referring to are called CSS3 shapes.  Here is a link that looks pretty helpful in making some of the shapes:

http://www.css3shapes.com/